# ASP.NETにてGridViewを使っているのですが編集ができません｡

Tags: asp.net

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="800px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="行" DataField="GYO" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="日付" DataField="YMD" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="得意先" DataField="TKCD" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: `ASP.NST GridView 編集`といったキーワードで検索すると色々出てきますが、どのような場合にどう編集したいのか、出来ないという状況は何か、といったことを追記してください。あと詳細なフレームワーク名・ツール・動作環境とか版数なども。[GridView グリッド内のインライン編集](https://aspnet.keicode.com/controls/gridview-edit.php), [GridViewを編集モードにする方法](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=57636&KLOG=96), [GridViewの編集機能でテキストボックスの編集後の値sy](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=74894&KLOG=126), [GridViewを初めから編集画面にするには？](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=44280&forum=7&start=8) あとピンポイントなXAMLだけではなく、関連しそうなソースとか画面イメージとか諸々も追記した方が良さそうです。

Comment: TemplateFieldで入力エリアが表示されましたが
再度　分かりやすい編集にし直し投稿いたします。

Comment: 「TemplateFieldで入力エリアが表示されましたが」とのことですが、質問のコードにあった BoundField か TemplateField かは編集するのに関係ないですよ。編集モードにするか否かの違いです。