# ASP.NET GridViewにComboBoxを設定したいのですが方法がわかりません

Tags: asp.net

GridViewにDropDownListは設定出来るのですが,ComboBoxを設定したいのです。
理由は複数候補の選択+新規入力したい為。
しかしAjazToolKitにComboBoxはあるのですが設定できません。
どなたかご教授願いませんでしょうか。

**実行環境:**
NetFramework 4.0
Windows 10
VisualStudio 2010

```xml
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="195px" Width="362px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**　アイテムテンプレートにAjaxToolKitのComboBoxをドラッグしても反映されないのです｡
なので GridViewにComboBoxが現在追加出来ません｡

[image: アイテム]

Comment: この辺の記事が当たってはいなさそうですが、かすってはいるかもしれないので参考になるかも。[Ajaxtoolkit combobox in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41140161/9014308), [Ajax combo box in gridview appends the value I searched with the data that is bound from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11573432/9014308), [Cant find a combobox control in edittemplate in Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48026302/9014308)

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74740/asp-net%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a6gridview%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93 が放置状態です。状況が変わってそこでの Q&A は不要になって、このスレッドの質問になったということ？　であれば先のスレッドにはその旨書いてクローズしてください。

Answer (score 0):

> しかしAjazToolKitにComboBoxはあるのですが設定できません。

「設定できません」とはどういう意味でしょう？　単純に表示するということなら、DropDownList に代えて ComboBox を配置すれば良いはずですが。以下のように：

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="AAA" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="BBB" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="CCC" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
  </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

結果は：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問を編集しました。　AjaxToolKitのComboBoxをドラッグ出来ないのです｡又,エクステンダーからの追加画面にはComboBoxが表示されていません｡

Comment: 先に前のスレッドが放置状態なのを何とかしていただけませんか？

Comment: ところで、質問者さんは Teratail の https://teratail.com/questions/328297 の人と同一人物ですか？　環境が一致するのでそう思ったのですが、違ったら失礼しました。

Comment: ちがいますが? あなたのPGでは実現出来ているようなのですが私の方では回答のようなセットが出来ません｡